# How to disable shadow action bar (android 5.0)?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I am currently building an app that uses the material design theme as a base theme.

However the action bar has a dark shadow below the action bar. 
I have tried everything I can think of, but I can't seem to get rid of it. 
Here is a screen shot showing what I mean: 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_krkpxyd558V0p6a1NKZXFHeHc/edit?usp=docslist_api

If someone could tell me how I can get rid of it, I would much appreciate it.

Thanks 
Corey :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shadow is created by using elevation, here's how you can disable it programmatically:

```
getActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Comment: That was perfect! Thanks heaps :)

Comment: You can also do it in the styles with `<item name="elevation">0dp</item>` as detailed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27960435/change-elevation-of-actionbar-by-theme. Then you don't have to set it for every activity.