# Change Elevation of ActionBar by theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, android-elevation

I want to remove the shadow below the ActionBar.

I know that I need to change the elevation to 0dp, but I want to do it in the theme.

For Android 4.4- I use : `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>`

But is it possible for Android 5.0 ?

Comment: Set the elevation attribute in your Action Bar style.

Comment: Well, how exactly ? At the moment I have a veru basic theme that inherit Theme.AppCompat where I change colorPrimary etc.

Comment: You can find the answer in this other question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar/27203224#27203224

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As shown by Antonio Jose, here is an answer : [Remove shadow below actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar/27203224#27203224)

---

For Android 5.0, if you want to set it directly into a style use:

```
<item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
```

and for Support library compatibility use:

```
<item name="elevation">0dp</item>
```

Example of style for a AppCompat light theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
<!-- remove shadow below action bar -->
<!-- <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item> -->
<!-- Support library compatibility -->
<item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Then apply this custom ActionBar style to you app theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

For pre 5.0 Android, add this too to your app theme:

```
<!-- Remove shadow below action bar Android < 5.0 -->
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Comment: if you put `android:elevation` in styles it make the title elevated too, but if you just put `elevation` it works.